# suexec failing scriptalias without logs

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, suexec

I am trying to install gitolite 3 on a apache2 server. So I need to run a CGI script owned by `git:git`. My configuration for achieving this (based mainly on [this](http://linuxadminzone.com/quickly-setup-git-server-with-gitolite-gitweb-ssh-and-http-auth/)) is:

```
<VirtualHost myserver.com>
  ServerName myserver.com
  ServerAlias git
  SuexecUserGroup git git
  ScriptAliasMatch "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | info/refs | objects/(info/[^/]+ | [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
  /srv/www/gitolite_suexec_wrapper.sh/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I have is whenever a query match my stript alias regexp, the client receives a 403 and my apache errors logs (set to debug level) tell me the following:

```
client denied by server configuration: /srv/www/gitolite_suexec_wrapper.sh
```

My apache2 server has user wwwrun and group www. The suexec module is running, so I test everything is fine like this:

```
su -c "/usr/sbin/suexec2 true" wwwrun
suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
```

So this user can start suexec. Previously I had wrong permissions on my `/srv/www/gitolite_suexec_wrapper.sh` and had lines logged in `/var/log/apache2/suexec.log`, now I have nothing so I guess my rights are set up correctly regarding suexec and the wrapping script.

And I am still unsure if this script should be owned by `wwwrun:www` or `git:git` the owner of the script that I need apache2 to run. I guess from [suexec help](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) that it should be `wwwrun:www`, anyway I tried both and both did not work.

```
su -c "/srv/www/gitolite_suexec_wrapper.sh" wwwrun
```

Gives an output, so I think my permissions are set correctly on this script.

What should I also check? What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, I had to grant access to the script file like this (in the same virtualhost):

```
<Directory "/srv/www">
  <Files "gitolite_suexec_wrapper.sh">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

And then its good.